# Adding different object types to a c# 4.0 collection

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a function that returns objects of different types based on the parameter passed to this function.
Is it possible to add these different object types to a collection based on some identifier in C# 4.0?
Usually we do something like this
List or List
but i want one collection which can add object of any type.

Comment: Is the return type of your function object (or some interface that all object types it returns implement)?

Answer (score 13):

Instead of just making a `List<object>` like other posters are recommending, you may want to define an interface eg `IListableObject` that contains a few methods that your objects need to implement. This will make any code using these objects much easier to write and will guard against unwanted objects getting into the collection down the line.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is called `object`. Eg:

```
var objlist = new List<object>();
objlist.Add(1);
objlist.Add(true);
objlist.Add("hello");
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `object[]`, `List<object>`, [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx), [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx), ... but if those types have a common base type it would be better to stick to a strongly typed collection.

Answer (score 4):

Really your collection should be as specific as you can make it. When you say

> objects of different types

Do these objects have anything in common? Do they implement a common interface?
If so you you can specialise the list on that interface `List<IMyInterface>`

Otherwise `List<object>` will do what you want.

**Update**

No, not really.

I'm sorry but I'm going to question your design.
If you have a collection of different objects, how do you decide how to use one of the objects?
You're going to have a large switch statement switching on the type of the object, then you cast to a specific object and use it.

You also have have a similar switch statement in your factory method that creates the object.

One of the benefits of Object Orientation is that if you design your objects correctly then you don't need to do these large "If it's this object do this.Method(), if it's that object do that.OtherMethod()".

Can I ask, why are you putting different objects into the same collection? What's the benefit to you?

Comment: They do but i have framed it that way so that they share the same parent.Worst part is they have different implementation and additional methods.So if i give interface, i would miss out the additional methods in the individual classes. Is there a pattern implementation you could advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a collection which can add objects of any type then `List<object>` is the most appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

Collections in earlier versions of C# (not generics) can contain any kind of objects. If they're value type, they will be boxed into object.
When you need to use them, you can just cast it to the original type.

You may use `List<Type>` to hold the type information, if that's what you want. And Type[], Hashtable, etc. are also fine. You can use typeof operator to get the type or use Object.GetType().

Answer (score 1):

Also check out Dynamic type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

It will basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion:

```
public class ParamValue
{
    object value = null;
    public ParamValue(object val)
    {
        value = val;
    }

    public string AsString()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public int AsInt()
    {
        return int.Parse(value.ToString());
    }

    public int? AsNullableInt()
    {
        int n;

        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out n))
        {
            return n;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public bool AsBool()
    {
        return bool.Parse(value.ToString());
    }

    public bool? AsNullableBool()
    {
        bool b;

        if (bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out b))
        {
            return b;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class Params
{
    Dictionary<string, object> paramCol = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Add(string paramName, object value)
    {
        paramCol.Add(paramName, value);
    }

    public ParamValue this[string paramName]
    {
        get
        {
            object v;

            if (paramCol.TryGetValue(paramName, out v))
            {
                return new ParamValue(v);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Use param class as a collectio to your values, you can convert the return to every type you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Tuple of Genric Types

```
public Tuple<T, T> MySuperMethod()
{
   int number = 1;
   string text = "Batman";

   return new Tuple<int, string>(number, text);
}
```

> The .NET Framework directly supports tuples with one to seven
>   elements. In addition, you can create tuples of eight or more elements
>   by nesting tuple objects in the Rest property of a Tuple object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.100).aspx